# Using DISM to repair system image. Image vs Source?

Tags: windows-10, dism

I'm trying to repair my system files as they seem to be corrupt, but doing a simple `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` tells me that I need to *specify a `Source`*.

Using [this Microsoft page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image) I'm trying to figure out how to properly specify the source, but I don't know the difference between the `Image` argument and the `Source` argument and anything I try to put just says "Unable to access the image."

I have the windows 10 installation iso that I used to install my OS on my external harddrive (`X:\Windows 10\<long-iso-name>.iso`).

I've also right-clicked and mounted the iso, so the contents are mounted on the E: drive (e.g. `E:\sources\install.wim`).

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?
I've tried lots of things, `DISM /Image="X:\Windows 10\" /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:E:\sources\install.wim:1` being my last attempt.

EDIT: Oh, whoops left off the `:1` somehow. Though I don't know what `Index` it is talking about, I just found another post that included it and it didn't seem to work for me.

EDIT:
Ran the command requested:

> Details for image : E:\sources\install.wim
>
> Index : 1 Name : Windows 10 Home Description : Windows 10 Home Size :
>   14,413,158,633 bytes
>
> Index : 2 Name : Windows 10 Home N Description : Windows 10 Home N
>   Size : 13,604,145,696 bytes
>
> Index : 3 Name : Windows 10 Home Single Language Description : Windows
>   10 Home Single Language Size : 14,412,406,152 bytes
>
> Index : 4 Name : Windows 10 Education Description : Windows 10
>   Education Size : 14,685,500,905 bytes
>
> Index : 5 Name : Windows 10 Education N Description : Windows 10
>   Education N Size : 13,879,693,484 bytes
>
> Index : 6 Name : Windows 10 Pro Description : Windows 10 Pro Size :
>   14,686,067,526 bytes
>
> Index : 7 Name : Windows 10 Pro N Description : Windows 10 Pro N Size
>   : 13,880,235,200 bytes
>
> Index : 8 Name : Windows 10 Pro Education Description : Windows 10 Pro
>   Education Size : 14,685,430,667 bytes
>
> Index : 9 Name : Windows 10 Pro Education N Description : Windows 10
>   Pro Education N Size : 13,879,622,346 bytes
>
> Index : 10 Name : Windows 10 Pro for Workstations Description :
>   Windows 10 Pro for Workstations Size : 14,685,465,552 bytes
>
> Index : 11 Name : Windows 10 Pro N for Workstations Description :
>   Windows 10 Pro N for Workstations Size : 13,879,657,681 bytes
>
> The operation completed successfully.

Comment: With the release of 1903+ you have to specify the index within the image you want to use.  What index value entirely depends on the version of Windows your using.

Comment: Not entirely sure what that means, but I'm using `Windows 10 Home 10.0.17763`.

Comment: Run *Dism /Get-ImageInfo /imagefile:C:\test\images\install.wim* against your install.wim but use the correct path and edit your question with a screenshot of the relevant information.  You don’t actually indicate the problem with the command you last tried.  I can tell you used the incorrect index though (index 1 is Windows 10 Professional more than likely)

Comment: I'll try that once my system lets me. Not even task manager will respond right now. Would do a full reset but that window won't appear either....

Comment: 17763 is Version 1809.  The above is good information, but DISM works properly with Version 1809. You may need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link (use the second section (download) and run in place. Use the option to Keep Everything

Comment: @Shelby115 - What errors did you get exactly when you ran the repair command you said didn't work?  It is odd that you can't use `/Online` as that is typically one would use.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it said "Source" could not be found. Going to take another stab at it today, I tried John's suggestion and it ran, but then just kind of closed and did nothing. Thinking I might just have to full reformat since I can't access the menu for doing a reset.